# Finding the number of positive integer pairs $(a,b)$ satisfying $a^2 + b^2 < 2013$ and $a^2b\mid b^3 - a^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Find the number of positive integer pairs $(a,b)$ satisfying $a^2 + b^2 < 2013$ and $a^2b \mid b^3 - a^3$.

Let $\dfrac{b^3-a^3}{a^2b} = \dfrac{b^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{a}{b} = k$, where $k$ is an integer. Rearranging a bit, we can get the cubic equation $\dfrac{a^3}{b^3} + k\dfrac{a^2}{b^2} - 1 = 0$, or, substituting $\dfrac{a}{b} = x$, we have $x^3 + kx^2 - 1 = 0$. Since $a$ and $b$ are integers, the roots need to be rational. However, I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

We will show that if $a\ne b$, there is no solution.

For $a^2b \mid b^3 - a^3$, both $a$ and $b$ must be even. Hence: $a=2m, b=2n$. Then $m^2n\mid n^3-m^3$. By the method of infinite descent, there is no solution.

Answer (score 2):

A more direct way: Denote $d = (a, b)$, $a = a_0 d$, $b = b_0 d$, then $a^2 b \mid b^3 - a^3 \Leftrightarrow a_0^2 b_0 \mid b_0^3 - a_0^3$. If $a_0 > 1$, for any prime $p \mid a_0$, because $(a_0, b_0) = 1$, then$$
p \mid b_0^3 - a_0^3,\ p \mid a_0^3 \Longrightarrow p \mid b_0^3 \Longrightarrow p \mid 1,
$$
a contradiction. Thus $a_0 = 1$, and analogously, $b_0 = 1$. Therefore, $a = b$.

Comment: — Just to clarify, is $d$ the gcd? Also, if $p | a_0$, the reason why $p | b_0^3 - a_0^3$ as well is because $p | a_0^2b_0$ and that divides into $b_0^3 - a_0^3$, right?

Comment: @Helena To both questions, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the tools allowed, I would just calculate in a spreadsheet.  We know $b \lt \sqrt {2013}$ so $b \le 44$  I made a spreadsheet with $a$ ranging from $1$ to $44$ in a column and $b$ ranging from $1$ to $44$ in a row.  Using mixed references I was able to put a formula for $(b^3-a^3)/(a^2b)$ in the $1,1$ cell, then copy right and down to fill it all.  A quick visual scan shows the only cases that give an integer are $a=b$, so we need $a=b\lt \sqrt{\frac{2013}2}=31+$ and there are $31$ pairs.